# Find the Sum of all possible distinct remainders

Tags: modular-arithmetic

[image]

**My Approach**

I assumed the prime number of the form $6k+1$ when the prime number is greater than $3$.

$$(6k+1)^3=\frac {216k^3 + 1+108k^2+18k}6.$$Assuming $\color{blue}{k=1}$ I get The answer as $\color{red}{1}$.

Comment: There are the special primes $2$ and $3$. Their cubes have remainders $2$ and $3$ respectively.  All the rest have shape $6k+1$ **or** $6k+5$.  You should end up with $11$.

Comment: the answer is 6 since the possible remainders of an odd prime is 1 or 5. And once cubed and summed we get 6.

Comment: @AndréNicolas How? $2$ and $3$ have a remainder sum of 5.Any other number will have a remainder of $1$.So,I get 6.How you get 11?

Comment: Primes of the form $6k+1$ give remainder $1$. Primes of the form $6k+5$ give remainder $5$. Total is $2+3+1+5$.

Comment: By the [Congruence Power Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) $\bmod 6\!:\ (6k\pm1)^3\equiv (\pm1)^3\equiv \pm1 \equiv 1,5,\,$ and $2^3\equiv 2,\ 3^3\equiv 3,\,$ so the sum $= 1+5+2+3=11\ \ $

Answer (score -1):

In fact, any prime $>3,$ can be written as $6k\pm1$

and $(6k\pm1)^3\equiv\pm1\pmod6$ as $6k\pm1\equiv\pm1$

Comment: Yes I assumed only 6k+1 form.But the Ans is not given in the options according to you.